# Make div with top margin ignore div above it

Tags: css, margin, html

I have two divs, one above the other, i would like the bottom div to ignore the one above it. The bottom div has the top margin property. By ignore i mean i dont want the top div to be counted when it is using top margin (but rather to push against the wrapper which contains both divs.)

Comment: what?  I just woke up, so maybe I'm not comprehending correctly what you're asking....I'll read this again when I'm done drinking my coffee.  Sounds like you want the top div to stay flush at the top of the wrapping div?

Answer (score 1):

Just use absolute positioning for the top div.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you could change the top div to position:absolute; which will take if out of the flow of the document.